# What's the fastest way to copy the current file to another folder in VIM

Tags: vim

We have several code branches, and sometimes we need to sync the file from one branch to another. e.g

We have the following file in branch A and branch B. After edit file a.sql under branchA, i need to copy it to the file under branchB. Currently I have edit it, save it, open the folder under branchA, go to x\y\z, copy a.sql, then open the folder of branchB, go to x\y\z, and past the file here. This action has to be done many times, is there any way to simplify this? Or any plugin could help?

```
c:\branchA\X\Y\Z\a.sql
c:\branchB\X\Y\Z\a.sql
```

Comment: Is this under some sort of version control?  If so, shouldn't you be doing merges instead of completely overwriting the other branch?

Comment: Use the shell and use `cp`?

Comment: Or just `:w /path/to/other/file.sql`? (`:w! ...` may be needed depending on your overwrite settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:saveas /path/to/other/file
```

Just like with any editor.

Answer (score 0):

With my just-published [DuplicateWrite plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4722), that would be

```
:edit c:\branchA\X\Y\Z\a.sql
:DuplicateWrite c:\branchB\X\Y\Z\a.sql
```

From then on, every `:w` on the file in `branchA` will also be done on the same file in `branchB`.